# How do i register a selector from a SEL variable?

Tags: iphone

I am having a `SEL` variable  which I want to set in my button selector.

My code goes like this:

```
GridView *ObjGridView=[[GridView alloc]initWithFrame:frame]; 
[[NSBundle mainBundle ] loadNibNamed:@"GridView" owner:ObjGridView options:nil];

CATEGORY *ObjCategory=[arrCategory objectAtIndex:index];
//do something 

ICON *ObjIcno=[ObjCategory.arrIconObjects objectAtIndex:indexIcon];

[ObjGridView.button1 addTarget:self action:ObjIcno.handler forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];
```

`ObjIcno.handler` is a SEL variable (which is previously set by a selector )

Like this:

```
arrSectonProductivityTools=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:[[[ICON alloc]initWithIcon:@"firefox.png":@"Firefox":@selector(FirefoxCickEvent:)] autorelease],nil];
```

I set the selector in my class this way, which is setting properly but I am not getting the click event on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ObjGridView.button1 addTarget:self action:ObjIcno.handler forControlEvents:UIControlStateNormal];
```

should be:

```
[ObjGridView.button1 addTarget:self action:ObjIcno.handler forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

For more options besides UIControlEventTouchUpInside, do cmd+mouse click on UIControlEventTouchUpInside.

Comment: Thanks Buddy,i dont have much Idea about this ,but it is Simple

Comment: 'UIControlStateNormal' (and UIControlStateDisabled, etc) can be used to style the button for different states (thus the UIControlState-type). So the button can have a 50% alpha (or whatever) when it's disabled and a 100% alpha when it's enabled. The UIControlEvent types are for the events (see the name).

Comment: Thank you Buddy,  just one more help                                         I have a View And i want to refresh it with the LandScape and PorTrait orientation .but i dont Want to do in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method . Can You Suggest me a Best Way to do it.

Comment: That totally depends on your app and what you want. You could add a refresh button for example ;)